# Trying to Remove all printers tied to an old print server

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe, printer

Recently my hospital shut down our old 2008RT print server. We sent out documentation for users to set up to the new printers by simply navigating to the print server. for the most part people are able to set up to the new server. but the majority of users have such an abundancy of printers on the old server that its confusing them, and no one seems to want to take the time to pull all the old printers as well as any added by the IS department will require admin creds to pull.

Is there any easy powershell loop/if statement or even a cmd line I can write that will target all printers on my old server?

Comment: If the computers are domain managed, it is easier to use group policy to delete all printers and then add the right ones.

Comment: computers are on a domain yes. but the issue is most users use different printers (we have roughly 70 printers) as well as some staff that travels between different facilities

Comment: It does require setting up everything right once, yes. But you can use Security Groups to bind printers to people or computers and narrow the list down so people get the right printers. Once setup, everything goes automatically always for current and new users.

Comment: Alternatively, create a group policy to just remove all printers and then instruct people to add the printer again.

Comment: Is there not an easy way to only remove printers from an old print server say remove all from "oldprintserver01" vs pulling everything

Comment: Its possible, but not easy. Can be done with powershell, but requires extensive knowledge of the language.

Answer (score 1):

First navigate here
in and administrative command prompt

```
C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US>
```

then type:

```
cscript prnmngr.vbs  -u ad\admin -w "password" -d -s computername -p printername
```

Where -u is an administrative domain user

> -w is the password

> -d delete

> -s is the computer name to delete the printer from

> -p is the printers name

In addition the command supports the -l or list all printers flag.

You could then parse the list of printers, and execute a for-next loop to delete the offending printers and not the good printers.

Comment: You may have to use the prnport.vbs script as well to remove the printer-ports that are no longer used. Just removing the printer in most cases leaves the port-definition in place. This is a major nuisance as (for network-connection based ports) Windows tries to reconnect to them on every reboot. Even if there is no printer attached to those ports anymore.